# Android tablet confused about its screen density

Tags: android, android-layout

BLUF: Can an android tablet be confused about its screen density?  How does one *un*confuse it?

Background: I have two "identical" Android tablets (same manufacturer, same model, same physical screen size, same resolution).

Tablet A self-reports a density of 160dpi.  Tablet B reports 213dpi.  If I make a layout using *actual pixels*, both outputs look identical.  That tells me their densities are actually the same.

If I make a layout using DP's, Tablet B renders all the screen elements way too big.  I believe it is doing this because it "thinks" it has a higher screen density and must therefore scale the screen elements up to compensate.  But I don't think it does.  I think they are the same.

So...  how can I change the value the Android tablet uses to determine its screen density?  How did the incorrect value get put in there?

And is it even possible for two screens that are the same physical size and the same resolution to have different densities?  (Density=resolution/size, right?)

Specifics:
Android 5.1.1 (64-bit)
CPU: Quad-Core ARMv8 Processor (VFPv4, NEON)
Renderer: Mali-400 MP2
GPU version: OpenGL ES 2.0
Kernel: Linux v3.10.65

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

More research reveals that the screen density that Android uses to render the display is set in the ROM by the manufacturer at build time.  It is not computed by Android in any way and it is *not* necessarily the value you would get by simply dividing the resolution by the screen size.

So, in the case of my question, even though the physical screen densities are actually the same on my two tablets (layouts built using actual pixels display the same size on both tablets), the manufacturer has elected to set one tablet to a higher screen density.  Android will therefore upscale all dp-specified layouts to compensate for the "higher" density.

*Why* the manufacturer would do that, I still don't know.  But why my two tablets show different densities is at least answered.